# setCropBoxData from cropperJS does not work

Tags: cropperjs

I am using cropperJS, and I am trying to use the `setCropBoxData`, but this does not work and in Documentation I don't find clear examples how to use it. Please, if someone could help, that would be amazing.

This is my function:

```js
function createCropper() {
    data = new FormData();
    var file = $('#file')[0].files[0];
    $('#' + globalId).attr('src', window.URL.createObjectURL(file));
    $('#img2').attr('src', window.URL.createObjectURL(file));
    var image = document.getElementById('img2');
    cropper = new Cropper(image, {
        aspectRatio: Cropwidth / Cropheigh,
        autoCropArea: 0.65,
        restore: false,
        center: false,
        highlight: false,
        cropBoxResizable: false,
        toggleDragModeOnDblclick: false,
        built: function () {
            cropper.setCropBoxData({ width: "100", height: "100" });
        }
    });
    cropper.crop();
}
```

I also tried:

```js
function createCropper() {
    data = new FormData();
    var file = $('#file')[0].files[0];
    $('#' + globalId).attr('src', window.URL.createObjectURL(file));
    $('#img2').attr('src', window.URL.createObjectURL(file));
    var image = document.getElementById('img2');
    cropper = new Cropper(image, {
        aspectRatio: Cropwidth / Cropheigh,
        autoCropArea: 0.65,
        restore: false,
        center: false,
        highlight: false,
        cropBoxResizable: false,
        toggleDragModeOnDblclick: false,
        built: function () {
            cropper.cropper("setCropBoxData", { width: "100", height: "100" });
        }
    });
    cropper.crop();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved it ... refer to my solution on this post: [setting cropbox data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30537406/how-to-set-crop-box-in-jquery-cropper/51729286#51729286)

the `setCropBoxData()` function did not work for me either, but after studying and several trials, I found a way to initialize the width and height using the data property:

```js
 data:{
   width: 240,
   height:  507,
 },
```